# Adding mock data to WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a WebBrowser control

```
webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Navigate("File.html");
```

The file has the HTML markup for the page. I have some mock data which I want to insert in the html file. Is there a way to do that ? The mock data binds with the controls on the html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 IHTMLTxtRange txt = (IHTMLTxtRange)Document.selection.createRange();
 txt.pasteHTML(HtmlString);
```

where

```
public IHTMLDocument2 Document
 {
      get
      {
          return webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      }
 }
```